# Infinite Ajax loop

Tags: ajax

My problem is very simple. I have a javascript that updates an html page everytime it gets a new ajax request. Here is the fetched php:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['sowhat'])) {

$file="hello.txt";

while( !file_exists($file) ) {
    sleep(1);
}

unlink($file);
$RESPONSE="ok";
echo json_encode($RESPONSE);
```

}

I need the javascript to send a query again every time it gets an ok response from the php. How is this achievable? I have tried with a basic infinite loop but the page crashes.

```
    $.when($.ajax( "json_test.php?sowhat="+"kkk" )).done(function(result){

    console.log(result);
    console.log('done');

    thisone.parent().hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500)
    thisone.parent().prev().show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500)

    // AJAX AGAIN, FOREVER

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you use a `setTimeout` - how are you getting the data from php? Is it an endpoint i.e. rest?

Comment: I included the php above. I thought of a settimeout except that would imply that I know when the request is coming, and it's random, I don't know the amount of time between each request...